# Casl/vue $can function is returning false, but user has that permission

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, casl

I am using *@casl/vue* plugin for user permissions management in vue cli project as shown in this sample repo by *casl plugin author* [sample(vue-blog)](https://github.com/stalniy/casl-examples/tree/master/packages/vue-blog). Here is my code
*ability.js*

```
export default (store) => {
const ability = store.getters.ability
ability.update(store.state.rules);
return store.subscribe((mutation) => {
    switch (mutation.type) {
        case 'ROOT_LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            var formattedRules = [];
            if (mutation.payload.permissions.length > 0) {
                formattedRules = mutation.payload.permissions.map(perm => {
                    let formattedObj = {};
                    formattedObj.actions = perm.substr(0, perm.indexOf(' '));
                    formattedObj.subject = perm.substr(perm.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                    return formattedObj;
                })
            }
            console.log(formattedRules)
            ability.update(formattedRules);
            break
        case 'ROOT_LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
            ability.update([{actions: 'read', subject: 'all'}])
            break
    }
 })
}
```

I am getting `rules` from *rest-api* on login and formatting and saving it to `localStorage` in casl/vue format `{actions: 'someAction', subject: 'someSubject'}`.
Here is 
 *storage.js*

```
export default (options) => (store) => {
 if (localStorage.state) {
    const storedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.state)
    store.replaceState(Object.assign(store.state, storedState))
 }
 return store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    if (options.destroyOn && options.destroyOn.indexOf(mutation.type) !== -1) {
        return localStorage.removeItem('state')
    }
    const newState = options.storedKeys.reduce((map, key) => {
        map[key] = state[key]
        return map
    }, {});
    localStorage.state = JSON.stringify(newState)
 })
}
```

and *store.js*

```
/*
 * FOR USER PERMISSIONS MANAGEMENT ON UI */
 import {Ability} from '@casl/ability'
 import abilityPlugin from "@/shared/store/ability"
 import storage from "@/shared/store/storage";
 ...
 export default new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: [
      storage({
        storedKeys: ['token', 'rules'],
        destroyOn: ['ROOT_LOGOUT_SUCCESS']
      }),
      abilityPlugin
    ],
 ...
 mutations: {
    ROOT_LOGIN_SUCCESS(state, data) {
        let formattedRules = [];
        if (data.permissions.length > 0) {
            formattedRules = data.permissions.map(perm => {
                let formattedObj = {};
                formattedObj.actions = perm.substr(0, perm.indexOf(' '));
                formattedObj.subject = perm.substr(perm.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                return formattedObj;
            })
        }
        state.rules = formattedRules;
        state.token = data.token;
    },
    ROOT_LOGOUT_SUCCESS(state) {
        state.rules = [];
    },
 },
 ...
 getters: {
     ability() {
         return new Ability()
     }
  },
}
```

*main.js*

```
/*
* FOR USER PERMISSIONS MANAGEMENT ON UI */
 import {abilitiesPlugin, Can} from '@casl/vue'
 Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, store.getters.ability)
 Vue.component('Can', Can);
```

Inside Vue component template I am using it like this 
*index.vue*

```
          <v-btn
            v-if="$can('delete', 'department')"
            color="error"
            dark
            @click="uiShowConfirm({content: 'Are you sure?', 
                     callBack: deleteConfirmed})"
        >
            <v-icon class="mr-2">mdi-delete</v-icon>
            Delete
        </v-btn>
```

But it is returning `false` 
 Some help is really appreciated! 
I have saved `rules` like this
[image]

Comment: What casl version do you use?

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi `@casl/ability@5.2.2` and  `@casl/vue@1.2.2`

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi Hi, can you help with this, please

Comment: If you get null for `relevantRuleFor` it means that casl doesn’t a rule for provided action/subject pair. From what I can tell is that the shape of `rule` object is wrong. `actions` was deprecated in v4 and removed in v5. Try to replace `actions` with `action`

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi changed `actions` to `action` and that worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `@casl/ability@5.2.2` and `@casl/vue@1.2.2` 
As said in the comments by @SergiiStotskyi

> If you get null for `relevantRuleFor` it means that casl doesn’t a rule for provided action/subject pair. From what I can tell is that the shape of `rule` object is wrong. actions was deprecated in v4 and removed in v5. Try to replace `actions` with `action`

After changing `actions` to `action` that worked. 
Thanks @SergiiStotskyi 
Casl is a great library